# b = false vs if (b) b = false

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, switch-statement, case

I am processing `test.c` file and trying to count single line comments in it.

When I spot two consecutive `/` characters, I set `slc` trigger to `true`.

And when I reach the end of line, I need to set `slc` trigger to `false`.

Of course `\n` character clearly indicates the end of single-line comment.

```
switch (character)
{
    case '\n':
        slc = false; // single-line comment ended
        break;
```

But when `\n` character found, `slc` could be either `true` or `false`.

```
switch (character)
{
    case '\n':
        if (slc) slc = false; // single-line comment ended
        break;
```

Is there any difference between these two code blocks?

How should I write?

Comment: For the first code, you should change the comment, `// no single-line comment from here` or something, since the newline need not end one.

Comment: The only difference is that the latter will generate more code if you turn off the optimizer ... the behavior will be the same. Isn't that obvious? `slc` will necessarily be false at the end of the statement.

Comment: @JimBalter Not so obvious for me. I have not been sure which operation is easier for computer: to assign some new value to a variable, or to check some condition.

Comment: These are never things that you should consider when writing code. Micro-optimization is a wonderful way to make extremely fast, extremely unmaintainable, highly bug-ridden code. Let the compiler do the work; focus your optimizations on the algorithms you use. Never optimize before a profiler tells you that you need to, and where.

Comment: I asked whether it isn't obvious that behavior is the same, but you responded about what's "easier for the computer", which is a different subject. It's also bizarrely stated ... if you mean "which operation is **faster**" then just say so. The fact is that just doing the assignment is considerably faster on modern computers; unpredictable branches suck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the first form. Adding an extra `if` check which doesn't affect the functionality of your code, only its readability, is bad practice. You should always write the most concise way possible that doesn't obfuscate the intention of your code. Since in this case your intention is always for the variable to be `false`, simply set `slc = false`.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, that was just of interest, will there be any difference for computer. And will compiler add a condition to check variable state?

Comment: If you want to be absolutely sure, write it both ways and disassemble the binary to see what the compiler does. I suspect it would optimize out the check unless you disable optimization. It would cost at least a couple of clock cycles to check the value of `slc`, plus having to use `jmp` instructions can be rough for thread prediction and pipelining if done haphazardly.

Comment: Just compile with -S to get the assembly code; no need to disassemble.  With optimisation (eg -O2) the two methods will be exactly the same.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits "will there be any difference for computer" -- what **sort** of difference? The behavior will be identical. "And will compiler add a condition to check variable state?" -- It certainly will if `slc` was declared `volatile`. Otherwise, it might or it might not, even though you told it to.

Answer (score 0):

Top one does the trick and why bother with the `if`